# Cannot produce top level JAXBs from wsdl file using xjc compiler and binding file

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl, xjc

I am trying to generate top level JAXBs (Using binding file) from a local wsdl file.

The binding file (binding.xjb) contents are given here:

```
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
```

The command I am using is the following:

```
xjc -wsdl getShops.wsdl -b binding.xjb
```

and the wsdl file is given [here](http://services.e-prices.gr/wsdl/getShops.wsdl)

It successfully creates jaxb classes but they are nested classes in a single file.

Is this an unsupported feature of -wsdl flag of xjc compiler or am I mising something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the XSD schema from wsdl.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://new.webservice.namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="getShopsRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="ui" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="shoplist">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="shop"  maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="companyname" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Run the command:

```
xjc -wsdl getShops.xsd -b binding.xjb
```

output Console:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
namespace/webservice/_new/GetShopsRequest.java
namespace/webservice/_new/ObjectFactory.java
namespace/webservice/_new/Shop.java
namespace/webservice/_new/Shoplist.java
namespace/webservice/_new/package-info.java
```

Comment: I'm sorry forgot remove.